# error: package com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.util does not exist

Tags: java, spring, file

I have a Java 1.6 application that I need to use the FileCopyUtils.copy function for.

I include the library FileCopyUtils like so...

```
import com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
```

And then I call it like so...

```
File upload = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(upload);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileCopyUtils.copy(stream, out);
```

It actually runs fine when I run it locally.  However, when I try to build it using an Ant file, I get the following error:

> error: package com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.util does not exist

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you added libraries to your eclipse build path, not to your Ant build path.
Check your Ant build, in more details you need to place the libraries in location defined in your Ant build xml.
That could be one of the problems. I personally prefer Maven, than Ant ;)